# Python 3: Asyncio and Future

Tags: python-3.x

In the following code from https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/getting-started-with-asyncio-python/, it's using `asyncio.ensure_future` to wrap around a task.

However, it never set a future object inside `myCoroutine()`. Why the code still works?

```
import asyncio
import random

async def myCoroutine(id):
    process_time = random.randint(1,5)
    await asyncio.sleep(process_time)
    print("Coroutine: {}, has successfully completed after {} seconds".format(id, process_time))

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(10):
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(myCoroutine(i)))

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: So...? What is the question?

Comment: Question updated, please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicied create a `Future` object. `async def myCoroutine` already makes it so the call `myCoroutine()` returns something that behaves like a Future object, so that you can use `loop.ensure_future(myCoroutine())`